# Do experience buffs affect skill books?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I always assumed that [Skill Books](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skill_Books), [Trainers](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Trainers) and other [free skill boosts](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Free_Skill_Boosts) always gave you exactly 1 skill level. However reading about trainers on the wiki I see that:

> Training benefits from Sleeping and Standing Stone bonuses, though the XP so acquired will never result in advancing more than one level.

The same is also true for the free skills boosts.

So now I'm wondering if the same is true for skill books as well?

Comment: Although it is a legit question, the effect of skill books in Skyrim is so abysmally small that it is almost irrelevant. Plus the near impossibility to "save" these books because you would have no idea they grant a skill before using it, makes knowing this almost useless.

Comment: All the skill books are specific named books, so you might know if you played a lot of Skyrim. It's also extremely common to play Skyrim modded, and there are multiple popular mods that would help identifying unread skill books. You could also just quicksave before reading a book and load if it was a skill book. I like saving up my books to use when my skill is higher since they are more effective that way. Having 5 free skill ups at 90+ is really nice, and the possibility of an additional skill up or two due to exp buffs is worth investigating for me. I like minmaxing, and so do many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like experience buffs do indeed affect skill books.

I tested this in game with the guardian stones and an alteration book. Using The Mage Stone got me more exp than without.